# Symfony 4.4 Easyadmin: set permissions to access only my owned entities

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, rights, easyadmin

I have a colleague entity, which has a many to one relation with user entity.
I want to only have the ability to access colleagues attached to identified user.
This is for all CRUD permissions: list, edit, update, delete.

I've tried a lot of things, like DQL filter in easy_admin.yaml, but I can't manage to get authenticated user id.
I'm a Symfony junior, so I don't know how to do this and I must use Easyadmin.
So, it seems I can't use ColleagueController.php. Maybe with ColleagueRepository.php?
For the moment, everything is configured in easy_admin.yaml:

```
easy_admin:
   design:
      templates:
         label_null: 'null_value.html.twig'
   entities:
      Colleague:
         class: App\Entity\Colleague
         list:
            # dql_filter: "entity.user = 15"
            # dql_filter: "entity.user = '%env(AUTHENTICATED_USER)%'"
            # dql_filter: "entity.user = (SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = '%env(AUTHENTICATED_USER)%')"
            # dql_filter: "entity.user = (SELECT id FROM App\Entity\User WHERE email = 'aaa@gmail.com')"
            fields:
               - user
               - name
               - role
               - notes
               - { property: 'thumbnail', type: 'image', base_path: '%uploads_path%' }
            actions: ['show', 'edit', 'delete']
         form:
            fields:
               - user
               - name
               - role
               - notes
               - { property: 'thumbnailFile', type: 'vich_image' }
         show:
            fields:
               - user
               - name
               - role
               - notes
               - { property: 'thumbnail', type: 'image', base_path: '%uploads_path%' }
```

And my Entity\Colleague.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ColleagueRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ColleagueRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Colleague
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="colleagues")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $notes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={"default": 0})
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="colleague_thumbnails", fileNameProperty="thumbnail")
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    private $thumbnailFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * 
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $createdAt;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * 
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
        // var_dump($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser());
        // die;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRole(): ?string
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    public function setRole(?string $role): self
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotes(): ?string
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }

    public function setNotes(?string $notes): self
    {
        $this->notes = $notes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getThumbnail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }

    public function setThumbnail(?string $thumbnail): self
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getThumbnailFile()
    {
        return $this->thumbnailFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setThumbnailFile(File $thumbnail = null)
    {
        $this->thumbnailFile = $thumbnail;

        if ($thumbnail) {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Comment: Hello,You need to create custom voter : see doc here https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/security.html#custom-security-voters

Comment: Ok, but how do I call the voter with Easy admin? Because the show($ id) and edit($ id) methods do not seem to be called by this Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same answer as proposed on Linkedin: [easy admin advanced permissions](https://medium.com/@fabien.lemoine/gestion-avanc%C3%A9e-des-permissions-avec-le-bundle-easy-admin-sous-symfony-926b06c3a8a1). (french post content)
You can combine an event subscriber with a voter, simply follow this example.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do Easyadmin specific filtering this way:

config/packages/easy_admin.yaml:

```
easy_admin:
   entities:
      Colleague:
         class: App\Entity\Colleague
         controller: App\Controller\ColleagueController
```

src/Controller/ColleagueController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\EasyAdminController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class ColleagueController extends EasyAdminController
{
    protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
    {
        $result = parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter);

        if (method_exists($entityClass, 'getUser')) {
            $result->andWhere('entity.user = :user');
            $result->setParameter('user', $this->getUser());
        }

        return $result;
    }

    protected function createSearchQueryBuilder($entityClass, $searchQuery, array $searchableFields, $sortField = null, $sortDirection = null, $dqlFilter = null)
    {
        $result = parent::createSearchQueryBuilder($entityClass, $searchQuery, $searchableFields, $sortField, $sortDirection, $dqlFilter);

        if (method_exists($entityClass, 'getUser')) {
            $result->andWhere('entity.user = :user');
            $result->setParameter('user', $this->getUser());
        }

        return $result;
    }
    
    protected function createEditForm($entity, array $entityProperties)
    {
        $result = parent::createEditForm($entity, $entityProperties);

        if ($entity->getUser() !== $this->getUser()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }
        
        return $result;
    }
    
    protected function showAction()
    {
        $easyadmin = $this->request->attributes->get('easyadmin');
        $entity = $easyadmin['item'];

        if ($entity->getUser() !== $this->getUser()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $result = parent::showAction();
        
        return $result;
    }

    protected function deleteAction()
    {
        $easyadmin = $this->request->attributes->get('easyadmin');
        $entity = $easyadmin['item'];

        if ($entity->getUser() !== $this->getUser()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $result = parent::deleteAction();
        
        return $result;

    }
    
    /**
     * Create a colleague.
     */
    protected function persistEntity($entity)
    {
        $entity->setUser($this->getUser());
        $result = parent::persistEntity($entity);
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```